# How to call arrays from json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I call an array from JSON_DECODE? Example:

JSON script

```
{
    "callme":{"CallMeTo":"Called"}
}
```

In my case I want to be able to call it like this. (This does not work)

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode('{"callme":{"CallMeTo":"Called"}}');
    $json['callme']; // I want this to be equal to: array('CallMeTo'=>'Called')
    if($json['callme']['CallMeTo'] === 'Called'){
        return true;
    }
?>
```

Have any idea how this might be a true code?

Thanks, Richard.

Comment: If you want `json_decode` to return arrays instead of objects, set the second param to `true`.

Comment: I've done so, but still it does not allow me to call it as the example above. :(

Comment: Works for me https://3v4l.org/Wqvkd